# Find the continuous function that satisfies $f(x+1) + 3x^2 + 5x = f(2x+1), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-equations

Find the continuous function that satisfies $$f(x+1) + 3x^2 + 5x = f(2x+1), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
The only hint I have is that this can be solved by making both sides have a pattern, and turn it into a "iconic" function, and then calculate its derivative, and prove that it is monotonic. I kinda understand the hint, but the "iconic" function I found, $g(x)=f(x+1)-x^2-5x$, I can't find anything to do with it. Or maybe I should find the limit first?

Comment: How does the recursive formula for the "iconic" function look like?

Comment: Did you try to state that $f(x)$ is a second order polynomial function and see what happens?

Comment: hint: $g(2x) = g(x)$ for all $x$ implies $g(x) = g(x/2) = g(x/4) = \cdots = g(0)$ (why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=g(x)+x^{2}+3x$, putting this in the equation we get that $g(x+1)=g(2x+1)$. By putting repeatedly $x \to x/2$ gives $g(x/2+1)=g(x+1)$ ,$g(x/4+1)=g(x/2+1)$...By continuity we conclude $g(x+1)=g(1)=c$. So $f(x)=c+3x+x^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find one solution using the [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) $f(t)=at^2+bt+c.$

Then you can try to show that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two solutions then $f_1-f_2$ is constant.

Conclude that all solutions are on the form $f(t)=at^2+bt+c$ where $a,b$ have fixed values while $c$ is arbitrary.